# "Answer was accepted 1 time"?

Tags: support, tooltips

When I hover my mouse over any "accept" event in the reputation tab of a profile, I see a text box saying

[image: 1]

Does this message suggest that an answer can be accepted more than once? I think it probably doesn't, but I'm just curious why this message was formatted as such.

Comment: Unanswered MSE post: [Can we accept an answer more than 1 time? The reputation tab tooltip seems to think so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332456)

Comment: It will even say ["answer was upvoted 1 time"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKVKX.png) on *each* of the upvotes :D Note: I manipulated the underlying data.

Comment: It _might_ mean that the answer was accepted and unaccepted, therefore meaning the answer _was_ accepted once.

Comment: It's just a wickedly correct tooltip. It was accepted one time that one time.

Comment: Why is it an integer instead of a boolean?

Comment: Interestingly, the downvote tooltip only says ["post was downvoted"](https://imgur.com/Q1qLtj9)

Comment: How about the OP accepts answer X.  Then another answer is posted and the OP changes his/her mind, so Y becomes the accepted .  Then, OP reconsiders and re-accepts X

Comment: @0-1 because "Answer was accepted true time" sounds weirder :P

Comment: I guess "answer was accepted 1 time" is a past tense. The OP could remove it's accepted status and it should still show, "answer was accepted 1 time". If the OP decided to re-accept the answer, will it show, "answer was accepted 2 times"?

Comment: It might also mean "*this answer was accepted the first time*" or "*this is the first time an answer was accepted on this question*"?

Comment: Too bad there aren't bounties in meta...

Comment: @Anonymous on Meta.SE there are bounties, if you wanted to you can do one over there on the linked question.

Comment: @DavyM I have less reputation on SE meta then here, so starting a bounty would _really_ limit me.